# Is there a way to eliminate outside edge of padding in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, padding

So I've noticed when using padding() it creates an outside space/edge outside a view frame. **Is there a way to eliminate that outside edge?**

Here is `.padding(.top, 0)`
[image]

Here is `.padding(.top, 1)` the extra outside edge has appeared
[image]

Here is `.padding(.top, 10)` the outside edge remains on any padding above 1px from what I see.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("")
                .frame(width: 300, height: 20)
                .background(Color(.black))
                .cornerRadius(10)
            Text("")
                .frame(width: 300, height: 20)
                .background(Color(.black))
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding(.top, 0)//here you can change the 0 to 1
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you add demo code for that?

Comment: I went ahead and added it

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can add the padding before settings the background color if you want the background color to extend more?

Comment: I went added another photo to show specifically what it is I'm trying to do.

Comment: There is spacing on your VStack. VStack(spacing: 0) { ...

Comment: @purebreadd Nailed it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help! FYI - anytime you add a VStack, HStack, Scrollview, etc. they will have the default spacing between items, unless you explicitly say otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this happens is because the `VStack` automatically has its own spacing. Replace:

```
VStack {
    /* ... */
}
```

with:

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    /* ... */
}
```

This removes padding between each view within the `VStack`. I am assuming SwiftUI makes an assumption that if you want `0` padding, you want them touching, otherwise you likely want padding from within its own space within the `VStack`.

Comment: This was driving me crazy. So glad I finally found this solution. Thank you

Comment: Oh Apple .. whoever thought this was a good a idea is nuts